# How to sort/unique output using jq

Tags: json, sorting, unique, jq

I have json like below:

```
% cat example.json
{
    "values" : [
        {
            "title": "B",
            "url": "https://B"
        },
        {
            "title": "A",
            "url": "https://A"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort the values based on title. i.e. expected output

```
{
  "title": "A",
  "url": "https://A"
}
{
  "title": "B",
  "url": "https://B"
}
```

Tried the blow. Does not work:

```
% jq '.values[] | sort' example.json           
jq: error (at example.json:12): object ({"title":"B...) cannot be sorted, as it is not an array

% jq '.values[] | sort_by(.title)' example.json
jq: error (at example.json:12): Cannot index string with string "title"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to preserve the overall structure, you would use the jq filter:

```
.values |= sort_by(.title)
```

If you want to extract .values and sort the array, leave out the "=":

```
.values | sort_by(.title)
```

To produce the output as shown in the Q:

```
.values | sort_by(.title)[]
```

#### Uniqueness

There are several ways in which "uniqueness" can be defined, and also several ways in which uniqueness can be achieved.

One option would simply be to use `unique_by` instead of `sort_by`; another (with different semantics) would be to use `(sort_by(.title)|unique)` instead of `sort_by(.title)`.